# Appropriate SE Site for Unicode Question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to know the difference between two specific Unicode characters, but I can't figure out which site is appropriate.

The closest ones I could find were Stack Overflow, Super User, Code Review, and Writers.

However,

- Unicode isn't programming, as it seems closer to markup, to be honest, so Stack Overflow doesn't seem to work;
- Super User is for "computer enthusiasts and power users", but a lot of the questions on there seem to be more about more mainstream things than digital typographic differences, so that doesn't seem to fit very well, either;
- Code Review seems the most applicable, but I'm concerned this will come off as somewhat amateurish for such a site; and
- Writers would somewhat work since I use Unicode a lot primarily because I'm a writer and it's **extremely** useful in writing more uncommon typographic characters not found in contemporary computer frameworks. But still, I'm not so sure how many computer-y people I would find in a writing community; it typically seems like writers with a good amount of computer knowledge is few and far between...

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Which two characters and what is the nature of the question? The site you post on depends on more information than given here. For example, perhaps it fits in at http://japanese.stackexchange.com/ if it's a high level question about Japanese characters or presentation, or if it's a question about RTL control codes perhaps SU, unless it's in a programming context then perhaps SO, or if it's about representing an action with a symbol perhaps UX, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that info because I didn't want to waste your time. I figured this question was not to answer my question, but to direct me to a site where someone could. But yes, that would help.

Comment: The Unicode characters are U+2044 and U+2215.

Comment: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ may suit your needs if the question is related to languages and not to technicalities of Unicode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Post it on [Super User](http://superuser.com). There are currently 350 generally well-received questions [tagged unicode](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unicode) there, and the particular case you mention (U+2044 vs U+2215) seems appropriate there.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the expediency.

Answer (score 3):

Code Review would not be appropriate. CR is for reviewing existing code that functions as intended. Explanations are explicitly off topic.

I'm still not sure which site is best, but at least you can cross  one off your list of potentials.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. I didn't know that about CR. And no worries. As per Jason_C's answer, I posted it on Super User.